# Two app instances are created when click on deeplink from mail

Tags: android, deep-linking, intentfilter, android-deep-link

I'm navigating to the email app from **X** activity, I am getting an email from the backend.
On that email we have the link, once click on that link it is navigated to app **Y** activity.
In that process, two app instances are created.

navigating to email app activity and navigating from email app activity both are not the same.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".framework.deeplink.DeepLinkActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:noHistory="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="medicineprod.com" android:pathPrefix="/redirectpath" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="medicinetest.com" android:pathPrefix="/redirectpath" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="medicineapp"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```